# ZK how to remove waiting actions

Tags: action, zk

I have an textbox with onChange method and button to make some actions. But if I type some thing in textbox and not clicking any where , click that button, It calls onClick method and then onChange method.Or first onChange and then OnClick but I should disable all actions after that onChange method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the check to your onClick() method. The onChange() for a text box is fired after a certain period of time or after you deselect your component. If you deselect your component by clicking on a button it sounds pretty natural to me to get the onClik first and then the onChange. There is no way of controlling (as far as I know) these events, except on server side.

[Read this !](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Introduction%20to%20ZK/Event%20Driven%20Programming)

Keep in mind that you are developing a WEB application and not a Desktop Application. And event if the development of zk applications may look pretty similar to the desktop applications they are not and they have their limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

First for Textbox  onFocus method I disable next button , and user cant click it.

Second for Textbox onBlure method I enable next button. (To be fired onBlure action user should click somewhere on window or press tab and this fires onChange action)